# Angular ng-repeat, triggering an event **without** directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this element in one of my template:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="register in results.registers track by register.id"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the width of the last element of the ng-repeat - without using directive - so I can use it in the controller on another element who needs to match the width. 
For that purpose I thought to trigger an event and take the width from it's event-target properties, but not sure how to do this. Any ideas?

** edit **

For simplicity sake I said no directive, but in earnest it is a directive - albeit one with no separated scope. There are too many ties with parent-scope, methods and collections. I could go for inherited scope, but this can be a few hundreds items long, so duplicating the parent scope ~500 time doesn't sound like a good idea.

I apologize, it seems that I communicate poorly :/

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, tnx for your feedback - is it clearer now?

Comment: @Ohjay44, tnx for your feedback - is it clearer now?

Comment: Why dont you want to use a directive for that?

Comment: Please see my additional info at the top

Comment: @gush, look at my answer below. I gave you the work around with JQuery but I still strongly suggest using a directive, and can accomplish this in a directive while still keeping this simple and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Now I changed the answer according to revised question, below snippet should help you. If you want to minimize heavy watchers being intrued by angular then you may prefer to use this module https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

I have created another [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qS0jbTlrpjtRhv2GkVui?p=preview) if you can use jQuery and wants to track element's width on widows resize as well

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  $scope.getWidth = function (ele){
    var width = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(ele)).width;
    console.log(width);
    return width;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .bold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="n in items track by $index" id="item-{{$index}}">
      {{n}}
      <span ng-if="$last" >
           {{getWidth('item-'+ $index)}}
       </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I am aware of the $last property, but I need to get the width of the last item into the controller (so I can use it on some other element)

Comment: I tried but getting ui element from scope is quite difficult from scope without using directives. Any specific reason for not using directives? Or its just for technical capabilities/feasibility demonstrative purpose?

Comment: Please see my additional info at the top

Comment: I think then you must do the UI alignment by using css and/or design rendering logic by keeping track of $index

Comment: I updated my answer, please check. now this should solve your problem.

Comment: sorry about the delay, it does work! Few points, though:
1. It gets called 3 times, for some reason
2. Window re-sizing needs to be address (not an issue of your solution, just a side effect of my approach)
3. It is a bit of a hack

Comment: In #3 I meant the empty span that trigger the function. A bit of a hack, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I am understanding you, but if I am then you could just use a directive to accomplish that. I know you said you want to do it without a directive so I have also provided a jQuery / Angular combo to show how you can accomplish that but it isn't very pretty. A directive is the proper way to do this and it is cleaner.

jQuery/Angular way:

```
  <script>
    var validation = angular.module('myMod', []);
     angular.module('myMod').controller('mycontroller' , function($scope) {
        $scope.myArray = ['1', '2', '3'];

        $scope.myFunction = function(last, item, ev){
            if(last == true){
               setTimeout(function(){ 
                 var el = $(item).width(); 
                 console.log(el); 
               }, 500);
            };
        };
     });
 </script>
 <body ng-app="myMod">
    <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
      <div ng-repeat="item in myArray track by $index">
        <span id="myEle{{$index}}" ng-init="myFunction($last, '#myEle' + $index)">{{item}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Again I do NOT reccomend this way as it is somewhat jank and could be better accomplished with an angular directive. If you insist on not using a directive this will also accomplish what you need.

Here it is working in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1a12hqs/)